# Does Skyrim implement different endings?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Not much to add here — I would like to know if Skyrim implements multiple endings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no "ending" in Elder Scrolls games. There's the main quest line, but the game doesn't end: it just wraps up like any other quest chain.

That is, if you decide to finish the main quest line and

> Defeat Alduin

the NPCs related to that quest will react<sup>1</sup> to the outcome.

If you don't, or even if you do, you'll just keep playing until you get bored. NPCs will continue to react differently depending on what you've done throughout the game, not just in the main quest line.

---

<sup>Note 1</sup>: Depending on your actions, there's a specific cutscene that may or may not trigger:

> After [Season Unending](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Season_Unending), the Blades will demand that you [kill Paarthurnax](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Paarthurnax). If you don't oblige, Paarthurnax will tell you of his plans to reform dragons and teach them the Way of the Voice once Alduin is defeated.

Comment: Is joining the Imperial Army / Stormcloaks not part of the main quest?

Comment: It ties in along the way, but you aren't required to resolve it to complete the main quest.

Comment: @Raven Dreamer if you look at your quest log stats, you'll see 'Civil War Questline' listed along with the guilds, so it is not.

Comment: The mods, **[The Paarthurnax Dilemma](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/18465/)** or **[The Paarthurnax Fix](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/8426/)** will allow you to be on the good side of both the Greybeards and the Blades.

Answer (score 4):

The Answer to your question is like stationed above, it will never end.
Even the Dark brotherhood is set to have a never ending quest line, but it does have a main quest that can be finished. Which sadly is kind of short.

You have quest all over the place in this game, from going on quest that's related to Oblivion in origin an ones for Morrowind.

So it really just matters to have fun and play the game till you get bored, which seems to be hard to get bored of, LOL. Almost felt like quitting my job for the game!

Answer (score -3):

You can choose to kill parranthurnax or not but it does not change the ending

Comment: This adds nothing that hasn't already been said with more detail in existing answers.